# Google Places Search API return List

Tags: android, google-places-api

For Android, is the only way to pull a specific List of Places within an area still using the URL and JSON method of parsing this?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters

Or has Google added Android support for that yet?

Comment: At the moment only web service is available for Places searches in Android.